# Idiomatic way to express sentiment of "I thought you'd never ask!"

Tags: idiomaticity

In English, sometimes people exclaim, "I thought you'd never ask!" if they had hoped the other person would express interest in something particular, but said expression was late in coming.
This statement is said seemingly to express pleasant surprise that the conversation partner is interested enough to ask about the thing, while hinting at exaperation that they took a long time to do so.

What would be the closest equivalent thing a native German speaker might say?

(After my last question was downvoted, presumably because I didn't search hard enough first, I've added dict.cc to my repertoire, but this one isn't in there, either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply

> Ich dachte, Du würdest nie fragen.

You can also add "schon" after "dachte".

[image]

Comment: In colloquial context even the subjunctive may be dropped: *Ich dachte, du fragst nie*.